# Multiple Cells Nested IF Formula Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to write a formula in Excel from two different cells. Here is what I have:

```
IF C5="US" AND I5="C" THEN="1,000"
IF C5="US" AND I5="V" THEN="2,500"
IF C5="US" AND I5="F" THEN="2,500"
IF C5="NIFA" AND I5="C" THEN="1,000"
IF C5="NIFA" AND I5="V" THEN="2,500"
IF C5="NIFA" AND I5="F" THEN="2,500"
IF C5="West" AND I5="C" THEN="1,000"
IF C5="West" AND I5="V" THEN="2,000"
IF C5="West" AND I5="F" THEN="2,000"
```

Here is what I currently have:

```
=IF(C5="US",IF(I5="C","1,000",IF(I5="V","2,500",IF(I5="F","2,500",IF(C5="NIFA",IF(I5="C","1,000",IF(I5="V","2,500",IF(I5="F","2,500",IF(C5="West",IF(I5="C","1,000",IF(I5="V","2,000",IF(I5="F","2,000"))))))))))))
```

The issue I am having with this formula is that anything is not US in C5 returns as "FALSE" - all of the US are fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: make a table with Four columns The Criteria in the first two, A concatenation of the first two columns, then in the fourth put the desired output.  The use a simple VLOOKUP() : `=VLOOKUP(C5&I5,YourTableSheet!C:D,2,FALSE)`

Comment: seems like you can simplify it to `=If(I5="C","1,000",If(C5="West","2,000","2,500"))`

Comment: @slai your "simplification" seems incomplete.

Comment: @DirkReichel it only seems that way. The problem is that it will return a value with different inputs too.

Comment: @Slai "NIFA" and "V" will output nothing... you sure it is complete?

Answer (score 1):

This method separates the data from the look-up logic and is therefore *extensible*. It is a little similar to Scott Craner's first suggestion (in the comments) but is based on a 2D look-up.

If you arrange your data as per below, you can use this formula to get the answer:

`=VLOOKUP($B$6,$A$2:$D$4,MATCH($B$7,$B$1:$D$1,0)+1,0)`

Note that it is `MATCH(...)+1` to offset the first column containing the first set of look-up values. E.g.:

[image]

Which gives the correct result of 2500:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will cover all nine cases:

```
= CHOOSE((C5="us")+4*(C5="NIFA")+7*(C5="West")+(I5="C")+2*(I5="V")+3*(I5="F")-1,1000,2500,2500,1000,2500,2500,1000,2000,2000)
```

(and does not require a single ***IF***)

Comment: or directly a 2D array via index/mach to make it easier to extend later on (if there is need to)